# Microsoft Translator: Translation job stuck "inprogress"

Tags: azure, text, translation, document, translate

to give a bit of background.

I am trying to test out MS Azure's Translator service. I am trying to use the Python code on the Azure page [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/get-started-with-document-translation?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_ProjectOxford&tabs=python) to access and use the REST API provided, but no the SDK.

With the account I've set up, text translation seems to work fine. But, I am stuck with Document Translation. I am at price tier S1.

I've tested a small text file with around 1000 Characters, and it outputs to a translated text file without any problems. This means all the syntax, URL and SAS token work.

Now, I want to translate a bigger file, DOCX format. However, it has been stuck "inProgress" ever since. I can't delete the jobs either.

Since then, I've tried again with these:
DOCX to DOCX
DOCX to TXT
TXT to TXT
TXT to TXT (small size, about 1000 characters)

but all of the jobs are stuck and shown as "inProgress"

I've also tried to do batch translation where you just point to a container and let it translate everything in there. I've done this with 2 text files in the container, but they are stuck as well. I've put a response header below just for your reference:

> 200

> {"id":"55e5e07e-34b6-4192-0ff-4025cb6e2d20", "createdDateTimeUtc":"2021-10-23T18:13:54.0318023Z","lastActionDateTimeUtc":"2021-10-23T18:14:01.2862604Z","status":"Running","summary":{"total":2,"failed":0,"success":0,"inProgress":2,"notYetStarted":0,"cancelled":0,"totalCharacterCharged":0}}

Is there anyway to investigate why there are stuck like that, but not an error? Thank you.